# drawing image in cameraOverlayView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this code to create a UIImagePickerController with a custom `cameraOverlayView`. For testing purposes, the overlay's just supposed to be a circle that I draw in CircleView using a UIBezierPath. However, the circle drawn in the CircleView is not appearing in the overlay. The overlay is supposed to be a subclass of UIView which my CircleView is. Can you explain why the circle is not appearing when the overlay pops up?  I initialize the circleView in `viewDidLoad` and then set it to be the `cameraOverlayView` in `viewDidAppear`.

**viewController**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CircleView *overlay;
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
self.overlay = [[CircleView alloc] init];
```

**viewDidAppear**

```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay;
        picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

CircleView

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        self.shape = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(CGRectMake(0, 50, 50, 50))];


    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

  [[UIColor colorWithRed: (114/255.0) green: (5/255.0) blue:(46/255.0) alpha:1] setFill];
   [self.shape fill];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Your circle overlay view has zero size, because you create it with `init` instead of `initWithFrame:` (`init` falls back on a frame of `{0,0,0,0}`, because you have provided no frame information).
- Your circle overlay view does some important initialization in `initWithCoder:`, but this method is never called, since you are instantiating it with `init` instead. Thus its `self.shape` is nil and nothing is drawn in its `drawRect:`.

Comment: ok, thanks, since you're never supposed to call initWithCoder directly, I was at a loss for what to do. I tried this `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];` and now just have a black layer starting from y coordinate 50 down the screen.

Comment: ok, the black screen problem is solved by `self.overlay.opaque = NO;` but can you tell me how I can trigger initWithCoder in the above code? or would you just draw the circle inside initWithFrame (which actually works but I thought you weren't supposed to do that)?

Comment: Why would you _want_ to "trigger `initWithCoder:`? You have no coder; you are not being unarchived. You are being instantiated from scratch. As for drawing, you would draw in `drawRect:` just as you are doing.